# Excel - Update a bills due date to the following month once it has been paid

Tags: excel, date

Hi I am very new to excel so I apologise if this question is a bit trivial or even not possible. I am trying to create something to keep track of my bills.

The A column holds the name of the bill and the B column holds the date it is due to be paid. What I want to be able to do is that when I have paid a bill have some way to mark it as paid and then have the due date change to the next month (bills are due on the same date each month).

Is this possible and what should I be looking at to do this? Thanks for any help or suggestions

Comment: Thats a good point, marking the item as paid isnt as important as long as the date changes correctly I just wasnt sure how to let excel know when to update it, so i thought somehow marking it as paid might be an idea

Answer (score 0):

If you have a third column C "Paid on" where you enter the payment date, you could write an onChange procedure [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775%28v=office.15%29.aspx) that updates column B if a cell in column C was changed:

```
if target.column=3 then
   cells(target.row, 2)=application.worksheetfunction.edate(cells(target.row, 2),1)
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED (but I'd like to know whether this works!) Enter and select the number of days in the current month. Select the "mark as paid" date and Paste Special, Values with Operation Add, OK.